# Looping through an array of numbers and letters and extract only the numbers?

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, typeof

I would like to loop through an array of numbers and letters and extract only the numbers .
I tried using the typeof operator but my code doesn't seems to work

```
str = "55abcdef6ghij78"

function NumberAddition(str) {
    var numArr = [];
    str = str.split("");

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (typeof str[i] === 'number') {
            numArr.push(str[i]);
        }
        return numArr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the result to be the __sum__ of the numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you want only the numbers, then there are so many ways to do it. But the simplest would be using a RegEx,

   ```
   console.log("55abcdef6ghij78".match(/\d+/g).join(""));
   // 55678
   ```

   This finds all the consecutive digits (one or more digits) in the string and returns them as an array and we finally join everything together to get a single string.
2. If you want all the numbers to be separate elements in the array, then you can tweak the RegEx a little bit, like this

   ```
   console.log("55abcdef6ghij78".match(/\d/g));
   // [ '5', '5', '6', '7', '8' ]
   ```
3. If you want to group the numbers, [as you asked for in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000695/looping-through-an-array-of-numbers-and-letters-and-extract-only-the-numbers#comment46249195_29000721) then just don't join them

   ```
   console.log("55abcdef6ghij78".match(/\d+/g));
   // [ '55', '6', '78' ]
   ```
4. If you want to convert them to numbers as soon as you group them, you can `map` the result array to `Number` function, like this

   ```
   console.log("55abcdef6ghij78".match(/\d+/g).map(Number));
   // [ 55, 6, 78 ]
   ```

---

Apart from that, if you want to fix your program, then there two major mistakes.

1. `typeof str[i] === 'number'`.

   The elements in `str` will already be of type string only. So, they will never be equal to `number`. To fix this, you can use the classic trick,

   ```
   if (+str[i] == str[i])
   ```

   This converts the current string to a number and compares it with the string value of it. If they are equal, then it means that the current element is a digit.
2. Apart from that, the `return` statement is within the `for` loop itself.

So, your program can be fixed like this

```
function NumberAddition(str) {
    var numArr = [];
    str = str.split("");

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (+str[i] == str[i]) {
            numArr.push(str[i]);
        }
    }
    return numArr;                           // Outside the for loop
}

console.log(NumberAddition("55abcdef6ghij78"));
// [ '5', '5', '6', '7', '8' ]
```

But the idiomatic way to do this would be to use `Array.prototype.filter`, like this

```
function NumberAddition(str) {
    return str.split("").filter(function(currentChar) {
        return +currentChar == currentChar;
    })
}

console.log(NumberAddition("55abcdef6ghij78"));
```

But, the shorter version would be using `Number`, like this

```
console.log("55abcdef6ghij78".split("").filter(Number));
// [ '5', '5', '6', '7', '8' ]
```

Comment: I don't think he wants them joined though. I was about to type almost the same thing. ;)

Comment: I would like to extract the numbers , and then add them .
for example if str = "55abcdef6ghij78".
i would like the new array to be [55 , 6 , 78 ].

Comment: @AziCode - You can look through the array of matches and add them. The RegEx, as shown above, returns an array of matches.

Comment: @thefourtheye if  str = "55abcdef6ghij78" .
i would like the new array to be [ 55 , 6 , 78 ] . 
your solution seperates the digits .

Comment: @thefourtheye i checked the updated answer .
all the provided solutions gives an array with separated digits 
[ '5', '5', '6', '7', '8' ] 
how can i have [ '55', '6', '78' ] instead of [ '5', '5', '6', '7', '8' ]

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes I did check the methods 3 and 4 .
but how can i combine these methods with the solution where you used the for loop. because my goal is to make and addition inside the new array 
[ '55', '6', '78' ]

Comment: @AziCode All the programs I have shown in my answer are separate programs. I don't understand what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing the character as an Integer first, and then check the type.

```
if (parseInt(str[i])) {
    numArr.push(str[i]);
}
```

As pointed out. `typeof NaN` is also `number`. So `typeof parseInt('a')` won't work.

Comment: btw, `typeof` doesn't need parens :)

Comment: I prefer this answer because it corrects the OP's code instead of offering a completely different approach.

Comment: @onsmith I agree it corrects the original approach, but then again the OP may not have known about a different approach. The RegEx actually gives him exactly what he wants, quicker.

Comment: I agree that the regex is a quicker, better approach and it will probably be a good opportunity to see something new. But the OP specifically asked for a loop approach in the title of the post, and even provided some code to explain his/her thought process.

Comment: When I use this solution on this str = "55abcdef6ghij78", 
it extracts  only the first "5" , but i need to extract all the numbers .
it should look like numArr = [55 , 6 , 78 ]
but instead it gives me numArr = [ 5 ]

Comment: I've got news for you.  This doesn't work. `typeof parseInt("A", 10)  === "number"`.  See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/0c05c2bk/

Comment: @thefourtheye you explained how to do it the RegEx way ,
but is it possible to get the desired result using the for loop ?

Answer (score 1):

Some good answers, but the simplest way to me is to remove the non–digits first, then create the array, so:

```
var str = '55abcdef6ghij78';
str.replace(/\D/g,'').split(''); // ['5','5','6','7','8'];
```

#### Ooops

you want to keep sequences of digits, so *match* is better:

```
str.match(/\d+/g); // ["55", "6", "78"]
```

If you want to sum the numbers, use reduce:

```
function numberAddition(s) {
  return s.match(/\d+/g).reduce(function(prev, curr){return prev + +curr}, 0);
}

console.log(numberAddition(str)); // 139
```

noting that a for loop will usually be faster, but not enough to matter unless you're doing this a lot or with very big arrays of numbers.

PS. Don't forget to declare variables, and function names starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors.

Comment: how would you get [ 55 , 6 , 78 ] instead of ['5','5','6','7','8'] ?